# Android XMPP avoid resource conflict

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm using Smack and Openfire for my XMPP connection/server. But I've run into the **very** common problem (apparently) of resource conflicts. Can anyone tell me the proper way of handling a conflict?

Openfire is set to always kick the original resource (it's a bespoke platform, not open to the public). But I still get the error and don't get a new connection. My XMPP class is below.

```
package com.goosesys.gaggle.services;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManagerListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster.SubscriptionMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence.Type;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.goosesys.gaggle.Globals;
import com.goosesys.gaggle.application.AppSettings;
import com.goosesys.gaggle.application.Utility;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BackgroundXmppConnector extends Service
{
    private ConnectionConfiguration acc;
    private XMPPConnection xConnection;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new XmppBinder();
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private final int manualReconnectionTimer = (5 * 60 * 1000);

    private static int mInterval1m = (2 * 60 * 1000);
    private static int mInterval5m = (5 * 60 * 1000);
    private static boolean bConnecting = false;
    private static final Object connectLock = new Object(); 
    private static final Object checkLock = new Object();

    private final Runnable checkConnection = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            synchronized(checkLock)
            {
                Log.d("BXC", "Handler running - Checking connection");
                checkConnectionStatus();
            }
        }
    };

    private final Runnable killConnection = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            synchronized(checkLock)
            {
                Log.d("BXC", "Killing connection and restarting");

                // Manually disconnect and restart the connection every 5 minutes
                if(xConnection != null)
                    xConnection.disconnect();

                destroyConnectionAndRestart();
                new LoginTask().execute();

                mHandler.postDelayed(this, mInterval5m);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {   
        Log.i("BXC", "BackgroundXmppConnector Service has been created");

        // Checks the connection state every 1 minute //
        mHandler.postDelayed(checkConnection, mInterval1m);
        mHandler.postDelayed(killConnection, mInterval5m);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {   
        Log.d("BXC", "Xmpp Connector Started"); 
        new LoginTask().execute();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private void destroyConnectionAndRestart()
    {
        xConnection.disconnect();
        xConnection = null;     
        Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false;
        bConnecting = false;
    }

    private void setupConnection()
    {   
        Log.d("BXC", "Settting up XMPP connection");
        try 
        {
            if(!bConnecting && !Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning)
            {
                acc = new ConnectionConfiguration(AppSettings.XMPP_SERVER_HOST,
                        AppSettings.XMPP_SERVER_PORT);
                acc.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
                acc.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
                acc.setReconnectionAllowed(false);
                acc.setSendPresence(true);

                xConnection = new XMPPConnection(acc);          
                xConnection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void connectionClosed() 
                        {
                            Log.e("BXC", "Xmpp connection closed");
                            Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false;
                            Globals.numberOfDisconnects += 1;
                            //destroyConnectionAndRestart();

                            Utility.writeToLog(getApplicationContext(), "Xmpp Connection closed - disconnected# (" + Globals.numberOfDisconnects + ")");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) 
                        {
                            Log.e("BXC", "Xmpp connection closed with error: " + e);
                            Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false; 
                            Globals.numberOfDisconnectsOnError += 1;                            
                            // This is more than likely due to a conflict loop - it's best to disconnect and nullify
                            // our connection and let the software restart when it checks every 5 minutes
                            if(e.toString().toUpperCase().contains("CONFLICT"))
                            {
                                Log.e("BXC", "Conflict connection loop detected - Waiting");
                            }

                            Utility.writeToLog(getApplicationContext(), "Xmpp Connection closed with error [" + e + "] - disconnected# (" + Globals.numberOfDisconnectsOnError + ")");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) 
                        {
                            Log.i("BXC", "Xmpp connection, reconnecting in " + seconds + " seconds");
                            Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false;                 
                            bConnecting = true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) 
                        {
                            Log.e("BXC", "Xmpp reconnection failed: " + e);
                            Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false;     
                            //destroyConnectionAndRestart();

                            Utility.writeToLog(getApplicationContext(), "Xmpp reConnection failed with error [" + e + "] - disconnected# (" + Globals.numberOfDisconnects + ")");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void reconnectionSuccessful() 
                        {
                            Log.i("BXC", "Xmpp reconnected successfully");
                            Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = true;
                            bConnecting = false;
                        }           
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("BXC", "Already in connecting state");
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("BXC", e.getMessage());
        }   
    }

    public boolean sendMessage(Intent intent)
    {
        if(xConnection != null && xConnection.isConnected())
        {
            String jsonObject;
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if(extras != null)
            {
                jsonObject = extras.getString("MESSAGEDATA");
                Message m = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, Message.class);
                if(m != null)
                {
                    sendMessage(m);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("BXC", "Message to send was/is null. Can't send.");
                }

                m = null;
                jsonObject = null;
                extras = null;
            }

            Log.i("BXC", "Sending Xmpp Packet");
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /*
     * Sends message to xmpp server - message packet in form of
     * 
     * --------------------MESSAGE PACKET-------------------------
     * TO
     * -----------------------
     * FROM
     * -----------------------
     * BODY
     *      TRANSACTION-------------------------------------------
     *          MessageType
     *          --------------------------------------------------
     *          TransactionObject
     */
    private void sendMessage(Message m)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.d("BXC", "Sending transaction message to Xmpp Server");
            xConnection.sendPacket(m);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Packet sent to XMPP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void checkConnectionStatus()
    {
        Log.d("BXC", "Checking Xmpp connection status");

        if(xConnection == null || xConnection.isAuthenticated() == false ||
                xConnection.isConnected() == false || xConnection.isSocketClosed() ||
                Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning == false)
        {
            Log.e("BXC", "Connection to server is dead. Retrying");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection dead - retrying", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            destroyConnectionAndRestart();
            new LoginTask().execute();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("BXC", "Connection appears to be valid");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    // BINDER ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return mBinder;
    }


    // INTERNAL CLASSES //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public class XmppBinder extends Binder
    {
        public BackgroundXmppConnector getService(){
            return BackgroundXmppConnector.this;
        }
    }

    private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // First ensure we've got a connection to work with first
            if(Utility.hasActiveInternetConnection(getApplicationContext()) && 
                    ((!bConnecting) || (!Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning)))
            {
                try
                {   
                    //bConnecting = true;
                    Log.d("BXC", "Beginning connection");
                    synchronized(connectLock)
                    {
                        setupConnection();                              
                        xConnection.connect();  
                        Log.i("BXC", "Login credentials: " + Utility.getAndroidID(getApplicationContext()) + " " + AppSettings.XMPP_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
                        xConnection.login(Utility.getAndroidID(getApplicationContext()), AppSettings.XMPP_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);                   

                        xConnection.getChatManager().addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void chatCreated(final Chat chat, boolean createdLocally)
                            {
                                if(!createdLocally)
                                {
                                    // add chat listener //
                                    chat.addMessageListener(new BackgroundMessageListener(getApplicationContext()));
                                }
                            }

                        });                 

                        Presence p = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
                        p.setStatus("Out and About");
                        xConnection.sendPacket(p);

                        Roster r = xConnection.getRoster();                 
                        r.setSubscriptionMode(SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
                        r.createEntry(AppSettings.BOT_NAME, "AbleBot", null);
                        r.addRosterListener(new RosterListener(){

                            @Override
                            public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) 
                            {               
                                for(String s : addresses)
                                {
                                    Log.d("BXC", "Entries Added: " + s);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) 
                            {
                                for(String s : addresses)
                                {
                                    Log.d("BXC", "Entries Deleted: " + s);
                                }                           
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) 
                            {   
                                for(String s : addresses)
                                {
                                    Log.d("BXC", "Entries updated: " + s);
                                }                           
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) 
                            {   
                                Log.d("BXC", "PresenceChanged: " + presence.getFrom());
                            }                       
                        });
                    }           
                }
                catch(IllegalStateException ex)
                {
                    Log.e("BXC", "IllegalStateException -->");
                    if(ex.getMessage().contains("Already logged in to server"))
                    {
                        Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = true;                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false;
                        Utility.writeExceptionToLog(getApplicationContext(), ex);

                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                catch(XMPPException ex)
                {
                    Log.e("BXC", "XMPPException -->");
                    Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false;
                    Utility.writeExceptionToLog(getApplicationContext(), ex);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(NullPointerException ex)
                {
                    Log.e("BXC", "NullPointerException -->");
                    Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false;
                    Utility.writeExceptionToLog(getApplicationContext(), ex);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.e("BXC", "Exception -->");
                    Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false;
                    Utility.writeToLog(getApplicationContext(), ex.toString());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;    
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("BXC", "No active internet data connection - will retry");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void ignored)
        {
            if(xConnection != null)
            {
                if(xConnection.isConnected() && (!xConnection.isSocketClosed()))
                {
                    Log.i("BXC", "Logged in to XMPP Server");
                    Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = true;

                    mHandler.postDelayed(checkConnection, mInterval1m);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("BXC", "Unable to log into XMPP Server.");    
                    Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false;

                    destroyConnectionAndRestart();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("BXC", "Xmpp Connection object is null");
                Globals.backgroundXmppConnectorRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

From what I've read, openfire (when set to always kick) will always kick the original resource and then allow the new login to connect, but I'm not seeing this at all. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I've read, openfire (when set to always kick) will always kick the original resource and then allow the new login to connect,…

Terminating the other connection with the same resource, ie. the previous one, is one option to deal with it. Most, if not all, XMPP servers provide this policy option regarding handling resource conflicts.

I can't comment on why setting Openfire to "Always kick" doesn't work for you, but it certainly does for me. And IIRC there are no current bug reports in Openfire that tell otherwise.

There is also another trivial approach: If you get a resource conflict on `login()`, simply specify a different resource: `login(String username, String password, String resource)`.

Or even more trivial: If you don't care how what the resource String is, you can have the server auto assign one to you. Simply use 'null' as resource argument: `login(user, password, null)`.

Comment: To be fair, it's probably the way I'm coding the connection. Although I don't auto-reconnect. That said, specifying the resource string has solved it. So, thank you :)

Comment: [xnyhps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23606344/194894) remembered me that there is also the possibility that you can let the server auto assign a resource to you. This is the most simply and convenient method to avoid resource conflicts.

Comment: Let the server assign the resource is correct.  Note that you might be running into the "dueling resources" bug, where you're not looking at the error code of disconnect before reconnecting.  So it may be that your new client is connecting correctly, then immediately getting kicked off by the first client reconnecting.  Almost *every* XMPP client and library has had this bug at one point or another.

Comment: Hello @LokiSinclair , i face same error  **"Connection closed with error , conflict..."** How you can solve it ? and my code of connect is in activity in separate thread , how you handle service as above in your question ? How you call service while message arrives and send ? Please help me all because i find out solution for "conflict" from the last 15 day but still not solution... my chat working fine for some time but after some time connection conflict exception arrives.. so please help me to solve out this.. thank you...

Comment: You should follow @Flow's advice here. I'm no longer working on the project myself. However, I got around it by acting on the various connection exceptions. The conflict loop was the hardest part to get around. In this instance I set a timeout to reconnect after X minutes when I knew Open-fire would have dropped the connection reference.

Comment: ok thanks for reply , @LokiSinclair , i coded sames as **Flow**  advised ,  but still that , i tested all the answers of the stack overflow and try to implement that but no result... How you handle service with that ? means when you call service and stop service , its like same as we normal service call ?

Comment: @JosephMekwan you should really get up to speed with how to code services in Android. There are a few options (bound and unbound primarily) and the communication is different. Also be sure to put your connectivity code into a seperate thread, async task is an easy way to achieve this.

Comment: @JosephMekwan From what I remember of the project, I never stopped the service. Due to it's 'always-on' requirement, an active connection with HQ had to be available as often as possible, but, given that signal is patchy at best in rural areas, I did have to rely upon GSM at varying points. Create a background service (and as JamesW says: The connection code should be inside an AsyncTask), then upon the varying connection states, act accordingly. OpenFire/XmppServer should be set to auto disconnect clients after X seconds/minutes and have some timing code to pre-empt the conflict loop. :)

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to deal with resource conflicts is to not use a fixed resource unless you absolutely must. If your client specifies no resource when logging in, the server should assign it a randomly generated one which will never conflict.

There are very few reasons why you'd ever need to specify a fixed resource, as most clients hide the resource of your contacts anyway, and there are other reasons why having a new resource on every connection is advantageous (like avoiding a common bug with group chats getting out of sync because the group chat's server didn't realize the connecting user is actually a new session).

A big problem with fixed resources is reconnection loops, where, if the server is configured to kick the old conflicting resource, two clients kick each other repeatedly. You should make sure you don't automatically reconnect when receiving a resource conflict error.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I've never seen any evidence of a random resource identifier. It's always something like: "Smack" or another api library name. Until today I've never specified a resource name, but now, appending a random string to login function works a treat!

Comment: Support is a MUST in the XMPP Core RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6120#section-7.6. I don't have an OF server to test against, but the source indicates it supports it: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/bccab4bffb8dbdbe10f3b95736623bc868b80737/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/handler/IQBindHandler.java#L85.